# SELECT INTO statement not working in VB.NET, but works when ran directly in Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I am converting old VB6 code to VB.NET with ADO.NET (OleDB). This is my query that will create a blank table when ran in VB.NET, but then works when ran directly in Access. This code presumably also works in VB6, as I am using the same SQL:

```
SELECT qryAsOf.name, qryAsOf.type, 0 as opt, 0 as swap
INTO qryCon
FROM qryAsOf
LEFT JOIN qryLinked on qryAsOf.c = qryLinked.lc
```

I feel like this has something to do with the left join and select into being together, but like I said it is only VB that has an issue with it, Access handles it perfectly.

Thanks :)

Edit: more details --

Without the INTO line, this query returns all 600+ rows.

This DOES NOT WORK:

```
cm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE qryCon (etc...)"
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO qryCon SELECT ..." '(rest of query above without INTO line)
cm.ExecuteNonQuery
```

This DOES WORK:

```
cm.CommandText = "CREATE PROC qryCon AS SELECT ..." '(same select as above without INTO, again)
cm.ExecuteNonQuery
```

The CREATE PROC that does work is fine, except I need to insert data into it later, so I get errors about how I need an updatable table. I really want the end qryCon to be a table, but I can't seem to get that to work :(

*However, when I do something like this (using the stored proc (renamed) above which, if viewed in Access, is full of data)

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM storedProc"
dr = cm.ExecuteReader

while dr.Read
    cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO qryCon VALUES (dr.GetValue(0), dr.GetValue(1), dr.GetValue(2), dr.GetValue(3))
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery
end while
```

This DOES NOT WORK! By the way, I removed the concatenation in the query for readability. It is correct in the actual project.

Comment: What do you mean "not working" e.g. do you get an error message? Are you using Linked Tables (as `qryLinked` could suggest)?

Comment: It creates the table with the correct field names, but with no records. If I ran the query in access, it populates the table with 600+ records.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the INTO clause ? How many rows are returned? Also, as you're not using any columns from the joined table. what is the purpose of the join?

Comment: Can you post the VB code that you are using?  That might prove useful.

Comment: There is an iif statement that uses the joined table, I didn't include it here because I knew it wasn't the issue and it is messy. If I comment out the INTO clause everything returned. This led me to just do CREATE TABLE followed by INSERT INTO qryCon SELECT ... - this worked. Don't know why this SELECT INTO did not work when simpler ones do, oh well!

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. Don't know what I was looking at. I will update OP in a sec with more detail.

Comment: @Logan - Is your data source for this project Access or SQL Server? You mention Access as part of the original app, but for your updated version, where are you going to store your data?

Comment: @Dillie-O: what do you mean? No one mentioned SQL Server until you did.

Answer (score 0):

Select into syntax may not be supported in the middleware, which tends to be somewhat generic. The statement might have to be executed in"passthrough" i.e. native-syntax mode.

Comment: The middleware simply passes the SQL code off to the OLE DB provider. The SQL code looks to be valid native Access (ACE, Jet, whatever). Anyhow, they are not getting a syntax error.

Comment: @onedaywhen: You should provide some authority for your belief that SELECT INTO is indeed supported, especially if you're going to downvote a comment that says "may". Are you saying that you can include server-side functions in your sql statement in oleDb -- that anything goes as long as the back-end supports it?

Comment: which authority would satisfy you? The OP said, "works when ran directly in Access. This code presumably also works in VB6" but I can't even tell you whether they are, for example, connecting to the wrong database, using the 'wrong' OLE DB provider, etc.  Polite suggestion: if you do not know whether your assertion are true, hence your need to employ tentative language ("may not", "might have to", etc), consider putting them in a comment (which I can't downvote) rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your VB6/Access syntax functions where you would iterate through the query object itself when parsing the results.

For .Net, you want to leverage the newer ADO.Net library and use a DataReader (or DataAdapter if you need to work with the results more than once in your code without having to make a second trip to the database) object in order to process your query. You can find a nice overview of how to work with them on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx).

EDIT:

After your question was updated, you want your SQL query to be this:

```
SELECT qryAsOf.name, qryAsOf.type, 0 as opt, 0 as swap
FROM qryAsOf
LEFT JOIN qryLinked on qryAsOf.c = qryLinked.lc
```

and then you'll iterate through the results and parse the values through each loop (as found in the MSDN link with something like

```
If reader.HasRows Then
   Do While reader.Read()
      Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) & vbTab & reader.GetString(1))
   Loop       
Else
   Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
End If
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. Except the SELECT does not return any rows. Unless I do CREATE PROC whatever AS SELECT..., then "whatever" has 600~ rows (in Access). Even if I do CREATE PROC in the VB, and then using a DataReader on "SELECT * FROM whatever", there are no rows returned. Even though the whatever proc is filled when viewed in Access. This is very frustrating.

Comment: I think you've missed the point. The OP is using `SELECT..INTO..FROM` syntax, the aim being to create a new populated table in the database. `Console.WriteLine` will not create new rows in the database! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since my earlier comment about pass-through mode appears to have been downvoted, perhaps by @onedaywhen, I include this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681754(v=vs.85).aspx

> Jet OLEDB:ODBC Pass-Through Statement
>   (DBPROP_JETOLEDB_ODBCPASSTHROUGH)
>
> Indicates that Jet should pass the SQL
>   text in a Command object to the back
>   end unaltered.

The documentation seems to suggest that the SQL text can be altered by the middleware unless this feature is invoked. So I repeat, you might want to make sure that oleDB supports SELECT INTO syntax. I'm not saying that SELECT INTO is not supported -- just that it is an issue worthy of the OP's attention.

P.S. When talking to a database via a middle layer that is designed to support a variety of back-ends, it is a good idea, I think, to use pass-through mode when the statement contains a function like IIF() or a UDF, or any syntax, such as SELECT INTO, which is not universally supported.

P.P.S. Here's some additional info that might be relevant:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Comment: I think this is down the right path, but I cannot find anything on DBPROP_JETOLEDB_ODBCPASSTHROUGH in Google or anywhere to tell me how to use it, most examples that use pass through are old ADO code where you change the properties of the ADODB.Command object. Do you know how to do this for OleDB?

Comment: @Logan: not sure since I haven't worked with Access for a long time. I believe it would be done in the connection string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.80).aspx  or it might be possible to set this property to True somehow through the wrapper: Jet OLEDB:ODBC Pass-Through Statement"

Comment: @Logan: I am not sure how much of the old provider is exposed through the .NET layer.

Comment: @Logan: take a look at Paul Clement's QueryDef approach here to see if could be adapted to your purposes; you could encapsulate the SQL syntax and that might get oledb out of your hair: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/25e12c40-958b-49c6-8b5d-fab8d596eb63/